# WHY printer_list function is not working

Tags: php

I tried the below sample code to get the list of shared printers name but i did not get the expected result. Anybody explain me why it is happening?

```
<?php
   var_dump(printer_list(PRINTER_ENUM_LOCAL | PRINTER_ENUM_SHARED));
?>
```

Comment: What was the result you got, and what was the result you expected?

Comment: I shared my PC with some other PC named another1-pc. That PC is connected with USB printer. I can share that printer.But when i executed the above code, it doesn't display the printer name.

Comment: the `printer_*` functions are not part of the core PHP so presumably you have loaded the extension manually? Is this on a windows system?

Comment: i have allready included the extension which is needed for printer but also its not working for me thakxxxxx

Comment: Yes I restarted. But still i am getting the same problem. So anybody help me to do this task?

Comment: Facing same problem here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<?php
$printers = printer_list ( PRINTER_ENUM_LOCAL );
print_r($printers);
?>
```